# Linq query table column list

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, linq

Hi I am trying to output a list of items from a table over linq to a dropdown list

I am getting an error on the linq query: `Cannot implicitly convert generic.list<string> to generic.List<locations>`

Can someone help please? Thanks in advance.

```
public static void getlocation()
{

    DataClasses_AbintegroDataContext dc = new DataClasses_AbintegroDataContext();

    List<Location> locations = (
        from a 
            in dc.Locations 
        select a.Name).ToList();

    DropDownList ddLocation = new DropDownList();

    locations.ToList();

    ddLocation.DataSource = locations;
    ddLocation.DataBind();

    ddLocation.SelectedIndex = 0;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are selecting a single column `select a.Name` and then you are trying to store the result of `ToList` to `List<Locations>`. Your current query would probably result in `List<string>` which is not assignable to `List<Locations>`

You can fix that by selecting `select a`

```
List<Location> locations = (
        from a in dc.Locations 
        select a).ToList();
```

You also don't need `locations.ToList();`  in your code, since `locations` is already a list. That is just redundant and you are not even assigning the result of `ToList` to any other field.

**Edit:**
You need to set [DataTextField](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.datatextfield%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [DataValueField](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.datavaluefield%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property of your `DropDownList` as well like:

```
ddLocation.DataValueField = "ID"; //Whatever you need the ID to be when selected
ddlLocation.DataTextField = "Name";
```

If you just want to show names and your selected value would be name as well then you can do:

```
 DataClasses_AbintegroDataContext dc = new DataClasses_AbintegroDataContext();

    List<string> locations = (
        from a in dc.Locations 
        select a.Name).ToList();

    DropDownList ddLocation = new DropDownList();

    ddLocation.DataSource = locations;
    ddLocation.DataBind();
    ddLocation.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

Not really sure why you need to create `ddlLocation` inside your code, You can create that in ASPX code and just do the binding in code behind.

Comment: Hi Habib, I had it like this but then the name items wasn't added to the drop down, when debugging i can see there there under name but not sure how to select that single column from the dropdown

Comment: hi I had added DropDownList ddLocation = new DropDownList(); because I couldnt get my asp tag to be seen on the code behind :S

Comment: I have this on the ASPX             <asp:DropDownList Width="150" ID="ddLocation" runat="server" DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="ID" >

            </asp:DropDownList>

Comment: @user369616 as this answer works for you, I would request you to `accept` this answer and also `upvote` it.